# Adding cygwin on right click on windows explorer

Tags: cygwin, windows-registry

I wish to add a command on right click menu in explorer that opens current directory with cygwin.

For same I have successfully added these registries:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\directory\shell\cygwin]
@="c:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe --login -i -c \"cd '%1'; bash\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\drive\shell\cygwin]
@="c:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe --login -i -c \"cd '%1'; bash\""
```

but this adds the command only when on some folder or drive.
I want generic right click on explorer, on which, search gives me this registry to edit:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin]
@="c:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe --login -i -c \"cd '%1'; bash\""
```

My problem lies with the value of the key, which doesnt work on %1 but on some static value like /cygdrive/c

Could someone please tell me the proper way to pass current directory to the command,
also please refer me some basic and advanced pages for same.

Answer (score 8):

Better option - No registry edit -- 
http://perfect-blog-url.blogspot.com/2013/04/open-cygwin-with-right-click-no.html

> On Win 7:
>
> 1. Install Cygwin with the 'chere' package.
> 2. Right click and Open Cygwin as Administrator.
> 3. type "chere -i"  or "chere -i -t mintty" if you would like to use Mintty which I personally prefere.

Comment: Please add a bit of summary, the link _will_ break sometime.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to install the `chere` package first, and run it as `chere -i -s bash`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what the chere package does.  Instead of tweaking the registry entries yourself, it might be easiest just to install that.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually better than Cygwin’s `chere` in my opinion because it only
launches once instance of `bash.exe`. If you look in Task Manager you will
notice `chere` requires 2 instance of `bash.exe` to work. Not a huge deal but
unecessary and annoying.

```sh
'directory', 'directory\background', 'drive' |
% {'cmd /c start /d "%v" bash' | ni -f hklm:\software\classes\$_\shell\bash\command}
```

[Source](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/e0f1b501d6e3fa2e/windows.ps1#L51-L54)

Answer (score -1):

This is an extension to what @user219318 has posted. If that does not work, you may use this option.

Run the cygwin.bat as 'Run as administrator' and type the following command. You may replace the 'bash' below with your favourite shell, to view the list of shells do `cat /etc/shells`

```
chere -i -s bash
```

Or if you want mintty

```
chere -i -t mintty -s bash
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?